# Distribution of probabilistic toy model for voting in two-party system

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I briefly describe a model for voting in a two-party system, similar in spirit to probabilistic urn models. I will then give an equivalent formulation with which is easier to work (but would be more difficult to motivate). I ask my question and describe the progress I have made at the end.

---

**Model 1**

Imagine a mayoral election with two candidates, $A,B$, in a city with two types of residents: Conformists ($C$) and Defiers ($D$). These are the rules of the voting system:

- the residents of the city are randomly assigned an order, and each casts their vote in this order
- each voter can see the running tally of votes for the candidates
- if the resident is a Conformist, then they vote for the candidate who is in the lead. If neither candidate is in the lead, then they decide between $A,B$ at random
- if the resident is a Defier, then they vote for the candidate who is in the lead. If neither candidate is in the lead, then they decide between $A,B$ at random

This prompts many interesting questions about the distribution of the votes given a population $c$ Conformists and $d$ Defiers, which will be simpler to ask after considering the following equivalent model.

---

**Model 2**

Imagine a game with two types of participants: Maximisers ($M$) and Neutralisers ($N$). These are the rules of the game:

- the game starts at a certain (integer) score $S$
- the participants are randomly assigned an order, and each makes their move in this order
- if the participant is a Maximiser, then they increase $|S|$ by $1$. If $S=0$, they pick the sign at random.
- if the participant is a Neutraliser, then they decrease $|S|$ by $1$. If $S=0$, they pick the sign at random.

It is hopefully clear that this model generalises the first model; the first model is obtained by letting $S = 0$ (which we assume from now on) and viewing $S$ as tracking the difference between the number of votes held by candidate $A$ and candidate $B$.

---

It is then (perhaps) of interest to determine the distribution of the final score (which I will denote by $S^*$) given $m$ Maximisers and $n$ Neutralisers. I presume that the model is too complicated to do this in generality with any ease, but I hope an answer to the following question could give more insight.

**Question**: Let $n=m$ for all $m$. Then, what is the limit of the distribution of $S^*$ as $m \to \infty$?

Here is an example of a relevant elementary result which I deduced.

**Proposition**: Let $n=m$. Then, $\mathbb{P}(S^* = 0) = \frac{1}{m+1}$.

**Proof**: With some thought, I can convince myself that $S^* = 0$ iff at every time, the number of $M$s who have moved is always at least the number of $N$s who have moved. The solution to the corresponding combinatorial problem is given (rather pleasingly, given the framing of Model 1) by [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem). $\square$

A final basic result which I proved is the following lemma.

**Lemma**: $|S^*| \le m+1$.

**Proof**: By induction on $m$. $\square$